# Web scraping in R for CSV link on apple mobility webpage

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

I am trying to get the csv link from the following webpage
https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
page <- read_html("https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility")

url <- page %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%       # find all links
  html_attr("href") %>%     # get the url
  str_subset("\\.csv")
```

But this is returning the character(0). This page does have a csv file with download option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The website is generated dynamically, using Javascript. Have a look at `cat(html_text(page))`, this is all the HTML code `rvest` can receive. The part you can see when visiting the page is rendered by your browser. You might have a look at `RSelenium` to work with dynamic webpages.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked RSelenium. It looks too complicated to download a csv file. Will try and see if there's any other way.

Comment: Selenium has a lot of overhead, and a learning curve, that's true.

Comment: The CSV files do not seem to be in the webpage anymore